# D3 - access axis tick by index

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have an histogram drawn in D3. X-scale is ordinal.
When I hover specific datum on histogram with mouse cursor, I want the font-weight of corresponding tick text label on X-axis to become bold.
For that purpose I use

```
.on("mouseover", highlightTickCallback)
```

callback.
 
The highlightTickCallback function receives corresponding datum as first parameter, so I could calculate tick index by searching specific key in domain of X-scale. But now, when I have index of tick, I need to access this tick somehow, and I don't understand how could I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would work if you have the tick index:

```
d3.selectAll(".tick")
.select("text")
.style("font-weight", function(d,i) {return i == yourIndexValue ? 900 : 100})
```

That will restyle all your ticks so that anything that isn't the mouseovered value will have a light font and the one that is will have a bold font. Keep in mind this will collect all your ticks together, so if you have multiple axes, you'll want to specify the  element that you've hopefully put your axis ticks inside first:

```
d3.select("#axisX")
.selectAll(".tick")
.select("text")
.style("font-weight", function(d,i) {return i == yourIndexValue ? 900 : 100})
```

You could also filter the selection of ticks, which might make more sense depending on how much you want to do on mouseover:

```
d3.select("#axisX")
.selectAll(".tick")
.select("text")
.filter(function(d,i) {return i == yourIndexValue})
.style("font-weight", 900)
```

Comment: Sure. I knew that we could accept index as second parameter, but wasn't sure about order of nodes in selection. I checked documentation and it tells, that nodes go in document traversal order, so it should work.